# Adicionar e remover classes no Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Tenho uma card que vai aparecer em determinadas ocasiões. Como efeito estou usando o material design bootstrap para dar um ZoomIn. Estou usando o ng4-clickout para quando clicar fora do meu elemento ele aplicar a classe ZoomOut e sumir com o elemento.

Minha div:

```
<div #cardnotificacao [exclude]="'.fa,.fa-close,.fecharnotificacao,.ml-2'" (clickOutside)="teste()" id="cardnotificacao" *ngIf="mostraNotificacoes" class="card cardnotificacoes animated zoomIn">
```

Minha função responsável por mostrar esse elemento:

```
  tocouSino(){

    this.mostraNotificacoes = true;

  }
```

A função que quando clica pra fora deste elemento é chamada:

```
  teste(){

    let card = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#cardnotificacao");
    card.classList.add('zoomOut');

  }
```

No primeiro clique funciona, porém depois quando clico no elemento que chama a função tocouSino(), o meu card não é mostrado. Acredito que seja porque a classe zoomOut esteja nesse elemento.

Também tentei:

```
teste(){

    let card = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#cardnotificacao");
    card.classList.add('zoomOut');

    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.mostraNotificacoes = false; },1000); 
    }
```

Dessa maneira o elemento aparece e depois some rapidamente.

Também tentei:

```
teste(){

    let card = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#cardnotificacao");
    card.classList.add('zoomOut');

    setTimeout(()=> {
      card.classList.remove('zoomOut'); },100); 

    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.mostraNotificacoes = false; },100); 
    }
```

Mas o elemento continua aparecendo e sumindo mesmo quando eu clico no elemento que só chama a função responsável por mostrar o card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quem se interessar, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
  fechaCardNotificacoes(){

    let previewimg = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#cardnotificacao");
    previewimg.classList.add('zoomOut');

    setTimeout(()=>{
      previewimg.classList.remove('zoomOut');
      this.mostraNotificacoes = false;
    }, 300);
  }
```

Comment: Melhor usar o ng Class com base nessa popriedade mostraNotificacoes